# Codeigniter: get all query of on page

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I find the function `$this->db->last_query();` to get the last query execut on the page but i want to know if its possible to get all the query running on the active page ? I make a small debug toolbar and i want to display all the query of the page.

I search in the [Query Helper Methods](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/helpers.html) and on the [Queries](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html) but i find nothing.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not use CI's built in profiler for this? https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/profiling.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all take a look @your DB Connection in the database.php under application/config/

There is an option "save_queries" which should be set to true

```
$db['default'] = array(
    ...
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

After that you can access to all queries like

```
$queries = $this->db->queries;

foreach ($queries as $query)
{
    echo $query;
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me, this will work in codeigniter 4?